# System V - LIFO way

Tags: c, linux, posix, system

I'm using System V to manage a message queue.
I successfully made a working prototype, everything works as expected, however I would like to have a LIFO queue instead of FIFO (expected last `msgsnd` message sent is first read `msgget`).

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes if you manage correctly message types. `msgrcv` manual specifies:

> The argument msgtyp specifies the type of message requested as
>   follows:
>
> - If msgtyp is 0, the first message on the queue is received.
> - If msgtyp
>     is greater than 0, the first message of type msgtyp is received.
> - If
>     msgtyp is less than 0, the first message of the lowest type that is
>     less than or equal to the absolute value of msgtyp is received.

Then if you send messages with strictly decreasing `msgtyp`, an extraction with `msgtyp` equals to `LONG_MIN` will always give you the last sent message. `msgtyp` plays the role of a priority in this case, 1 being the greatest.

Comment: Thanks that's what I was looking for ! Tricky but it works.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is impossible.

The term "queue" means FIFO. See wikipedia:

> **Queue (abstract data type)**
>
> In computer science, a queue (/ˈkjuː/ KYEW) is a particular kind of abstract data type or collection in which the entities in the collection are kept in order and the principal (or only) operations on the collection are the addition of entities to the rear terminal position, known as enqueue, and removal of entities from the front terminal position, known as dequeue. This makes the queue a First-In-First-Out (FIFO) data structure.